# Variables (request attributes) not being passed to JSP EL tags

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el

I'm having trouble finding why my `setAttributes` aren't being passed into the corresponding EL tags in my JSP.

The servlet code:

```
    double total = 0;
    double warning = 10000;

    String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/homeitems.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));

    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        double price = Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
        total = total + price;
    }
    br.close();

    if (total > warning) {
        request.setAttribute("total", total);
        request.setAttribute("message", "WARNING: total value exceeds maximum value of $10,000");
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/admin.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("total", total);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/admin.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

I've tried stepping through with the debugger in NetBeans but it shows the `setAttributes` being executed.

The JSP page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>A1 Home Inventory</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home Inventory</h1>
    <h3>Admin Summary</h3>
    Total Value: $${total}
    ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

homeitems.txt file contents:

```
living room,desk,200.0
living room,couch,500.0
kitchen,knives,100.0
bathroom,tub,2000.0
garage,car,8000.0
```

This is the EL in my JSP where the attribute values should be shown - but nothing is populated for the request attributes `total` or `message` - when I load the page.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is the "Home Inventory" (admin.jsp) page displayed in the browser?

Comment: The servlet's Java code and the JSP page sysntex looks okay. By any chance EL is disabled within the _page_ or in the `web.xml`?

Comment: What version of servlets API and JSP are you using? According to this only JSP versions 2.0 or above support to EL: [JSP Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) .

Comment: when i load the page all the <h> tags are there and total value text just none of the el. can el tags be disabled for individual jsp's? cause i have el on other jsp pages and they work fine.

Comment: Yes, EL can be disabled for a page -or- an application. Can you edit the post and show the entire JSP page contents (if possible)?  I tried the EL syntax and your servlet code using request attributes - it worked fine.

Comment: How large is the file -  "homeitems.txt"? Is the file a one time read data, -or- is it read for each request?

Comment: You can try this: (1) comment the code related to file open, close, read and while loop, (2) Use a test value for `total` variable, (3) try the application -  it is possible you may find something.

Comment: First print `total` for debugging purpose.

Comment: i edited and added all the JSP code. I also added an example of the output in the text file that the Servlet will be reading from.

Comment: I tried commenting out the file open, close, read and loop,  I set the total to 11000 to try and set both EL tags but it didnt work.